# How to fix IntegrityError 1048 in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-import-export

So, i just made a upload feature to insert data into databases. Data inserted successfully into the database but show an error messages

[image]

Before, i tried to change the column name on my excel .. i thought it was the problem, but after i undo the changes to default .. error still happened.

Here's my view code
Views.py

```
 if 'uploaddatasiswa' in request.POST:
        dataset = Dataset()
        new_siswa = request.FILES['uploadSiswa']

        if not new_siswa.name.endswith('xlsx'):
            messages.info(request, 'Format tidak valid!')
            
        else:
            imported_data = dataset.load(new_siswa.read(),format='xlsx')
            for data in imported_data:
                tambah_siswa = modelUser(
                    username = data[0],
                    namadepan = data[1],
                    namabelakang = data[2],
                    password = data[3],
                    email = data[4],
                    jeniskelamin = data[5],
                    tanggallahir = data[6],
                    agama = data[7],
                    alamat = data[8],
                    telepon = data[9],
                    role = "siswa"
                )
                tambah_siswa.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/admin/daftarsiswa")
    return render(request,'tambahsiswa.html')
```

Models.py

```
class modelUser(models.Model):
    namadepan = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False, blank=False)
    namabelakang = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False, blank=False)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False, blank=False)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False, blank=False)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False, blank=False)
    jeniskelamin = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False, blank=False)
    tanggallahir = models.DateField()
    agama = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False, blank=False)
    alamat = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False, blank=False)
    telepon = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False, blank=False)
    jumlahkelas = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True, default=0)
    role = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False, blank=False)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

Tables[image: here]

Comment: share models.py file

Comment: I am 99% sure you have an empty line at the end of  your .xslx file

Comment: It's working now. I think so .. it's work after i tried to create a new xlsx file .. @NicoGriffioen. Thanks for your help.God bless & Have a nice day sir!

Comment: If you remove that line, it should work. You could probably add some validation before saving to get a more verbose error message. 
Have a look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects

`model.full_clean()` will check if all necessary fields are filled, as well as is all values are correct.